# Work item rules in Azure DevOps board: Parent STATUS (custom field) dependent on child STATUS

Tags: azure-devops, automation

I'm working in Azure DevOps and have some organisational restrictions so instead of using "State" we will use a custom field "Status" with 6 options:

- On Track
- Delayed
- Pending
- Done
- Removed
- Blocked

The rule we want is:
Parent status is restricted and dependent on child Status. If any of the children of a parent item have the Status as Blocked, the parent item is changed to Blocked. Same with Delayed. The Status of the parent cannot be changed from Blocked or Delayed until all children are in one of the other states. If all children are in any other state, the parent changes to on track and can be manually changed.

Help!

Comment: Can you explain more about what each status means and how it relates to your team process? To be honest, I think there are existing Azure DevOps features that satisfy most of these requirements, but I need more information first.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do this would be to utilise a webhook on your Azure DevOps Boards and have it updated via the DevOps API. With a simple serverless instance like Azure Functions you should be able to do this quickly and painlessly.